# difference b/w reference object and simple object?

Tags: php, oop

```
obj = &new classname() 
and 
obj = new className()
```

what is difference b/w use to create reference object and object? 
What is advantage use of reference object when we create object

Comment: `new classname` returns a pointer which is completely different from a "simple object"... if this is c++

Comment: OP, can you clarify whether this is PHP or C++? Surely it can't be both (and I suspect it is PHP because the first line is not valid C++)

Comment: hi brian i want to know in a php

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the return value of the new construct as reference is deprecated since PHP 5 (I think). This was valid (maybe necessary?) in PHP 4, but generates a STRICT warning in PHP 5.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL)
```

at the beginning of a test script should yield the message that the first variant is old coding style. See the [handbook](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) for more information (e.g. user comments)